# cannot find module '../package' on install shiny-server from source

Tags: r, node.js, ubuntu, shiny-server

I got a problem with the installation of [shiny-server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/) (R). When following the install instructions found at https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source , On the seccond-last step

```
(cd .. && ext/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js --python="$PYTHON" rebuild)
```

I get the following error:

```
node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../package'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/store/opt/shiny-server/ext/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:78:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/store/opt/shiny-server/ext/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js:13:11)
```

Any suggestions about what I should do to fix this?

Update: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 so i can't just install a pre-compiled version

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, so i can't use a precompiled version

Answer (score 0):

See the answer is you did not have all the build-essential.
So you need to install following things:

- python
- cmake
- gcc
- g++
- git

Here is the documentation for more information.

---

Specific to the error you mentioned:

> (cd .. &&
>   ext/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   --python="$PYTHON" rebuild)

Python is not installed or environment is not set `$PYTHON`
And make sure you install python 2.x (Really. 3.x will not work)

Comment: Python, gcc, g++ and git are all installed regularly (executables can be found in /usr/bin), cmake was installed in /opt/cmake-2.8.12.2/ because the precompiled version available trough 'apt-get install' wasn't recent enough to be usable for this installation. However, cmake isn't added to the PATH variable

Comment: What is the output for `which python` and `which python2`

Comment: /usr/bin/python, and the version is Python 2.7.2+

Comment: $PYTHON was also set (as /usr/bin/python) but i can't find python2 however

Comment: and $PYTHON --version is working (and giving Python 2.7.2+ as output)